# How to use embedded signing and send an email to other recipients Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

Basically I am using Docusign's recipient_view_request to create an embedded sign url for our client, but there are about 5 or so other signers that need to sign via an email being sent (the default behavior of Docusign envelopes. However, it seems that these emails are not being sent in sandbox. My question is it possible to utilize embedded signing and also email signing for the same envelope? How would I do so?

Edit: here is the code snippet I am working with (variable names changed to generic names). I do not have client_user_id property set for the roles that I want emails to be sent to. I am using docusign sandbox right now and it is not sending emails to other recipients.

```
234         # Signer
235         applicant = TemplateRole(
236             email=email,
237             name=name,
238             role_name='Applicant',
239             client_user_id='1',
240             tabs=tabs)
242         roles = [applicant]
246             g2 = TemplateRole(
247                 email=g2_email,
248                 name=g2_name,
249                 role_name='G2',
250                 tabs=tabs)
251             roles.append(g2)
252
255             g3 = TemplateRole(
256                 email=g3_email,
257                 name=g3_name,
258                 role_name='G3',
259                 tabs=tabs)
260             roles.append(g3)

310         envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
311             status="sent",
312             template_id=templateId,
313             template_roles=roles

348         # Create envelope api object
349         DocusignBase()
350         envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(DocusignBase.api_client)
351
352         results = envelope_api.create_envelope(
353             DocusignBase.accountID,
354             envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
355         envelope_id = results.envelope_id
356
357         authentication_method = 'None'
358
359         recipient_view_request = RecipientViewRequest(
360             authentication_method=authentication_method,
361             client_user_id='1',
362             return_url=return/url',
363             user_name=first_name + ' ' + last_name,
364             email=email
365         )
366
368         results = envelope_api.create_recipient_view(
369             DocusignBase.accountID,
370             envelope_id,
371             recipient_view_request=recipient_view_request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re:

> is it possible to utilize embedded signing and also email signing for the same envelope?

Definitely yes. Check that you are **not** setting the `clientUserId` attribute for the **remote signers** (signers who receive email invites to their signing ceremony).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my question with a code snippet of what I'm using. I'm using the python SDK, and in sandbox. Can you see why it isn't sending these email?. Are there certain settings I need to set in sandbox?

Comment: Actually, I figured out my issue, had nothing to do with Docusign API. Thanks